# return response correctly for jquery autocomplete in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am new to jquery and am having trouble with the autocomplete function. edit:I should mention I am using MVC with Codeigniter. My AJAX response is returning like this `[{"customer_name":"Adecco Management & Consulting S.A."}]`. It is also not all in a row it is each character in the dropdown like this

```
[
{
"
c
u
s
t
```

and so on. Here is my autocomplete script.

```
$('#cust_name').autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response){
        var request = {
            toSearch: $('#cust_name').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/researchDB/index.php/rdb_con/autoComplete',
            data: request,
            datatype:"json",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and my controller:

```
function autoComplete(){
    $data['id'] = $this->rdb_mod->autoComplete();
    echo json_encode($data['id']);
}
```

model:

```
public function autoComplete(){
        $toSearch = $_POST['toSearch'];
        $this->db->select('customer_name');
        $this->db->like('customer_name', $toSearch,  'after');
        $query = $this->db->get('research');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

input in view:

```
<input data-input-type="cust_name" id="cust_name" class="ids form-control search-query " type="text"  name="customer_name">
```

I am not sure I set up the jquery function correctly but the response includes the desired results, in the wrong format, when I type in the input. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Is your questions incomplete or is it me? I dont see anything from the second code line.

Comment: yes it was. I hit tab enter and it posted prematurely.

Comment: @AgashThamo. Must be you. Personally I think it was crystal clear, preferred the question before the update...

Comment: Well ok. Thanks for response.

Comment: I don't understand if the return of the request "/researchDB/index.php/rdb_con/autoComplete" is "1 character per row" or not. If that's the case, I suppose we need also the code of the method inside `$this->rdb_mod->autoComplete()`.

Comment: @Asenar model and input element added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer outside of SO and want to post the solution here for others.

controller: I needed to put the results into an array and pass that to the ajax response as one object.

```
function autoComplete(){
        $data['id'] = $this->rdb_mod->autoComplete();
        $results = array();
        foreach($data['id'] as $row){
            $results[]=$row->customer_name;
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
}
```

jquery: As far as I understand this section, I wasn't making use of the built in functions and therefore overwriting the request variable that autocomplete sets up.

```
$('#cust_name').autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response){
           $.ajax({
                url: '/researchDB/index.php/rdb_con/autoComplete',
                data: request,
                datatype:"json",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    var items = JSON.parse(data);
                    response(items);
                }
            });
    }
    });
```

model: didn't change much. I added distinct to limit dup values.

```
public function autoComplete(){
        $toSearch = $_POST['term'];
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('customer_name');
        $this->db->like('customer_name', $toSearch, 'after');
        $query = $this->db->get('research');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Thanks to all those who helped me with this!